# XAML Design Time Preview for SwapChainPanel Element

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, directx, c++-cx

So if I'm using a `SwapChainPanel` element in the XAML designer, I get a design-time error saying the element can't be created. I see this out of the box with the `SwapChainPanel` [sample app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-SwapChainPanel-00cb688b) from Microsoft. In Visual Studio 2013.3 I see an ugly "Cannot create an instance of "D3DPanel"." in the Design view for Scenario1.xaml.

I was wondering if there were a way to provide fallback data for this element so I see something in the designer and in Blend. I've found some examples for designer data for data-bound controls, but so far nothing for DirectX.

Edit: here's the stack trace from the designer in the Scenario1.xaml file from the SwapChainPanel demo. We seem to be able to create SwapChainPanels themselves, but when there's a custom C# class like D3DPanel, it chokes:

at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.InstanceBuilderOperations.InstantiateType(Type type, Boolean supportInternal)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.InstantiateTargetType(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.WindowsXamlPlatform.InstanceBuilders.GridInstanceBuilder.InstantiateTargetType(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.WindowsXamlPlatform.InstanceBuilders.FrameworkElementInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ViewNodeManager.CreateInstance(IInstanceBuilder builder, ViewNode viewNode)

The offending XAML element is something like `<renderer:D3DPanel x:Name="DirectXPanel1" Height="300" Width="300" />`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a [Microsoft Connect ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/959081/xaml-design-time-preview-for-swapchainpanel-element-in-windows-store-app) for this behavior, but it was closed a no fix.